# How to make a HTML5 animation like the one on Blackberry PlayBook startup?

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas, html5-animation

I just want to know how to code a animation like the one on the [startup of the Blackberry PlayBook](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WjO3lkqewJc) with big colored circles using HTML5 canvas and JS (with some JS drawing library?). Can the same be achieved? Can you give an approximation to code implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the tridentJS library for animations https://github.com/kirillcool/trident-js.
Its quite straightforward, easy to use and well documented. You will also find samples and approaches that are similar to your sample.

Comment: Can you please add example code to make something like what I want to make?

Comment: @GarciaWebDev Hey man, I created sample for you. Try it   https://bitbucket.org/vivanov/blackberry-playbook-animation-with-trident-js and another sample https://bitbucket.org/vivanov/starfield-with-trident-js

Comment: Hey man, thanks, great work!